# python Error: cannot convert argument to rgb sequence

Tags: python, plot, colorbar

this is my code:

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    a=[0.8358042069314231, 0.6024065701024207, 0.9617569162444223, 1.120885517331551, 0.9778266035872442, 0.8887086644135614, 1.129697816341799, 0.7201744522139227, 0.8664407952949176, 0.7341260712316454, 0.658510937374308, 0.8904146773410425, 0.8717757176749454, 0.8166459824393625, 0.8339372675079395, 0.8003634701144817, 0.7659874150298758, 0.588331305578084, 0.55522301812699, 1.170550069401354, 0.8591871445132889, 0.8791241895935374, 1.025333128737861, 0.7626055728517448, 1.078399671082715, 0.7055734855725923, 0.720798713206163, 0.6886333276632871, 0.8471288388621045, 0.8754780670153172, 0.8523708462663552, 0.7246874496850487, 0.8292394046416274, 0.7803767971215964, 0.8743477112471153, 0.9958969069407901, 0.6769431631803139, 0.8773467224566912, 1.000147098676991, 0.7696909697871333, 0.8737321588069848, 0.5382244141057999, 0.4713278235703561, 0.6646682699231433, 0.8142396110707529, 0.8010456498519396, 0.6230657827339223, 0.688395869330359, 0.9462232919128286, 0.8495316484723737, 0.9942093060309608, 0.5228577377120195, 0.8192451490174453, 0.7218109597938437, 1.094902533752046, 0.7918411571432902, 0.1853703245133316, 0.6526308267023782, 1.170724769758224, 0.7302772774120317, 0.9324328310595102, 0.4962678697988561, 0.3752720253093461, 1.071244603207015, 0.66615740139685, 1.403488959177528, 0.6038971390943845, 0.8096930613194361, 0.9225707844751444, 0.4648132597838837, 0.783465976417999, 0.587824043205004, 0.8696348536547795, 0.6087662565833588, 0.8114405187405719, 1.160979540670139, 0.4172098683725269, 0.8203049559312928, 0.5283513301434342, 0.9804213471244552, 0.8612093808286192, 0.9541602042466272]
aa=[0.5467142240969229, 0.9832349591334052, 0.6237246993961033, 0.0, 0.5831794244764199, 0.3514226975000825, 1.77109168097854, 0.6247138549785067, 1.664771783798592, 0.4247971724813068, 0.0, 0.2523393191582641, 0.4893039208326278, 0.9281078151898693, 0.5768011081148378, 1.108193038745785, 0.2456363621402149, 0.8617850242006354, 0.5267724873577896, 0.1577668980710197, 0.3256065201760527, 0.6198844334464519, 0.0, 0.4800467231453376, 0.41063682727516, 0.5888128461522766, 0.7914054193752765, 0.5364683892414501, 0.6300029971600053, 0.795956524973436, 0.8859314844820457, 0.0, 1.009933346883598, 0.3681143616052806, 0.673066247323437, 0.784823895306669, 0.6549928032683661, 0.6270061214399052, 1.15337367807155, 0.5136022829838987, 0.6315411393786611, 0.3271570452075644, 0.5957190842140955, 0.0, 0.4745979810598814, 0.305842741616707, 0.3842636886080335, 0.7196084371435851, 0.0, 0.312272760281443, 0.3554478389969122, 0.868091699158965, 0.5869574668164317, 0.5649192923746441, 0.0, 0.8057386703802037, 0.0, 0.501235379563183, 0.6103368504256358, 0.5247345586856612, 0.8227552208451726, 0.1186217840874107, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.063407586906356, 0.6192493545908646, 0.0, 0.8068052574049874, 0.3638468406214595, 0.9188082415772201, 0.5535302027459117, 1.204703404116142, 0.0, 0.6159298413053304, 2.113067884469592, 0.0, 0.8735339653162774, 0.5949939082731295, 0.0, 0.7042802775180598, 0.7582877313150294]
aaa=[27114, 25347, 25839, 23503, 25181, 27094, 23412, 27132, 25751, 23270, 24659, 25522, 25412, 24696, 24667, 23323, 23206, 24794, 26535, 26074, 25354, 24446, 25871, 25283, 25387, 26820, 24011, 23982, 24237, 26169, 24146, 25186, 25122, 25223, 23715, 24000, 24876, 23920, 24256, 26191, 24873, 23603, 27226, 24253, 25157, 25099, 24860, 23125, 25348, 25696, 24563, 25866, 24910, 27009, 25067, 27643, 23798, 28002, 27531, 25525, 25126, 24050, 24040, 24467, 25819, 25935, 25453, 25886, 26827, 26372, 26465, 24786, 24275, 26212, 23968, 29389, 23460, 26550, 25241, 24205, 24649, 24121, 24734, 24221, 26176, 24077, 27017, 22919, 24376, 25579, 24076, 28658, 26675]
plt.scatter(a,aa,color=aaa)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

I got this error:

```
ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "27114"
to_rgb: Invalid rgb arg "27114"
cannot convert argument to rgb sequence
```

how could i add colorbar with third data?

Comment: What it says. `27114` does not define a color.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `aaa` doesn't define matplotlib colors.
From the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html) :

> Matplotlib recognizes the following formats to specify a color:
>
> - an RGB or RGBA tuple of float values in [0, 1] (e.g., (0.1, 0.2, 0.5) or (0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3));
> - a hex RGB or RGBA string (e.g., '#0F0F0F' or '#0F0F0F0F');
> - a string representation of a float value in [0, 1] inclusive for gray level (e.g., '0.5');
> - one of {'b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k', 'w'};
> - a X11/CSS4 color name;
> - a name from the xkcd color survey; prefixed with 'xkcd:' (e.g., 'xkcd:sky blue');
> - one of {'tab:blue', 'tab:orange', 'tab:green', 'tab:red', 'tab:purple', 'tab:brown', 'tab:pink', 'tab:gray', 'tab:olive', 'tab:cyan'} which are the Tableau Colors from the ‘T10’ categorical palette (which is the default color cycle);
> - a “CN” color spec, i.e. 'C' followed by a single digit, which is an index into the default property cycle
>     (matplotlib.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']); the indexing occurs at
>     artist creation time and defaults to black if the cycle does not
>     include color.

Which means you need to transform your numbers to comply with one of these formats.

Comment: thanks for your responding. would you help me more? how could i transform 93 number in [0,0.1 ,0.2,....1]?

Comment: Oh wow, I'm late to the party on this one. I understand your problem is probably solved by now, but for anyone else reading this: That would be up to you. If there is a logic to which number should be which color, implement it. If not, yet you still want control, you can write a big dictionary with these numbers as keys and colors as values. If you don't care which color is which but you want it to be consistent, you can always use the number as a seed in a random number generator, or you can hash it and use part of the hex digest as a color, or do something else entirely.